# Can `sudo` alone be used to switch to another given a password?

Tags: linux, unix, golang

I am currently writing a program in Go and trying to implement a switch user functionality. However, I can't find a clean way of sending a password via stdin to `su`. `sudo -S` allows for stdin password input, but as this requires sudo rules to be setup it isn't ideal. So:

- Is there a clean way of programmatically using su? OR
- Can sudo alone be used to switch users?

Comment: sudo can be used without a password with the correct configuration, and sudo can be used to run a shell, which is often largely equivalent to switching to another user, so the answer is: "probably?"  Can you explain what you want to do in more detail?

Comment: The idea is to make a general use tool that won’t require any specific configuration. I want a way to run a command as another user, and programmatically supply a password.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading here, this sounds like a security problem waiting to happen.  I hope you're being careful with handling credentials (password) and execution of privileged commands / SUID-set executables and the like.  Good luck.